# Query taking too long and not using index

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, mysql-5.6

We have an events service which returns events filtered by id and event timestamp and ordered by primary column.

There is about 1.5 GB of data in this table

query:

```
SELECT event.eventID, event.orgID, event.objectType, event.action, event.objectID, 
       event.logEventID, event.eventTimestamp, event.userID, event.source, 
       event.additionalDetails, event.insertByUserID, event.insertDateTime, 
       event.modifyByUserID, event.modifyDateTime 
  FROM event 
 WHERE event.orgID = 100 
   AND event.eventTimestamp >= 1535046151000 
ORDER BY event.eventID ASC limit 10001;
```

Above query takes 14 seconds to execute.

If I remove ORDER BY event.eventID ASC, it takes 0.01 sec

Current index is on primary column idx1(eventID). We added a second index idx2(orgID,eventTimestamp) and still don't see performance improvement.

The query does not use the new index unless specified with "USE Hint".  It takes 7 seconds with use hint and providing idx2.

We are on mysql version 5.6

Any thoughts on improving execution time?

Comment: If you think Java's a factor you'll need to include the relevant Java code, otherwise that's just a distraction. What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Can it be the super long integer (at least 13 digits) in event.eventID ? Make a temp table sorted and with autoincrement on a "normal" id, and see how fast it will go to select from this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big suck is the `Using filesort` operation, we should see if we can get the rows returned in "index order" to avoid that operation.

I'd be tempted to add an index:

```
... ON `event` (`orgid`,`eventid`,`eventtimestamp`)
```

I'd also experiment with tweaking the query. While not strictly necessary, we could include the `orgid` column in the `ORDER BY` clause, since the conditions in the `WHERE` clause guarantee us a single value.

```
 ORDER BY event.orgid ASC, event.eventid ASC
```

The intent here to give the optimizer as much information as possible, that there's a suitable index for satisfying the `ORDER BY` clause.

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan.

We are trying to get MySQL to use an index range scan on `orgid` to return rows in "index" order by `eventid`. And then discard rows that don't satisfy the condition on `eventtimestamp`.

```
SELECT event.eventid
     , event.orgid
     , event.objecttype
     , event.action
     , event.objectid
     , event.logeventid
     , event.eventtimestamp
     , event.userid
     , event.source
     , event.additionaldetails
     , event.insertbyuserid
     , event.insertdatetime
     , event.modifybyuserid
     , event.modifydatetime
  FROM event
 WHERE event.orgid = 100
   AND event.eventtimestamp >= 1535046151000
 ORDER
    BY event.orgid ASC 
     , event.eventid ASC
 LIMIT 10001
```

If that's not sufficient to avoid the "Using filesort" operation, then we could try moving the condition on `eventtimestamp` out of the `WHERE` clause into a `HAVING` clause. (Replace the `AND` keyword with `HAVING`.)

---

An index omitting the `eventtimestamp` might be sufficient to get a reasonable execution plan.

instead of

```
... ON `event` (`orgid`,`eventid`,`eventtimestamp`)
```

this might work just as well

```
... ON `event` (`orgid`,`eventid`)
```

Comment: can you clarify why order of columns in index impacts query execution time.

Comment: @user1180969:  for accessing rows, the index gives a performance boost by very quickly eliminating vast swaths of rows from being examined... since rows are "in order" in the index.  there's an equality condition on the `orgid` column, and index with leading column of `orgid` makes it very fast to ignore rows that have `orgid` values lower than 100 and greater than 100.  that index lets us eliminate all those rows... all of the rows that satisfy that condition are all packed together into contiguous pages in the index

Comment: @user1180969:  when we request rows to be returned in a particular sequence (the `ORDER BY` clause, the server will need to perform a sort operation, and that can be expensive on large sets.  BUT...  the server can avoid the sort operation if rows can be returned in order using an index... rows in an index are stored "in order" based on the values of the columns in the index.  So an index with leading columns of (orgiid,eventid) can be used to return rows in the order required by `ORDER BY orgid ASC, eventid ASC` ,,, avoiding a potentially expensive Using filesort operation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use both  `WHERE` and `HAVING`.  Just use `WHERE orgID = 100 AND eventTimestamp >= somevalue`.

`SELECT lots of stuff ORDER BY something LIMIT count` is a notorious performance antipattern. Why? It sorts a whole mess of rows just to discard most of them.

You can make this better using a *deferred join*. Get the PK values of the rows you need in a subquery, then retrieve the details.

Try something like this for the subquery.

```
         SELECT eventID
           FROM event
          WHERE orgID = 100
            AND eventTimestamp >= somevalue
          ORDER BY eventID
          LIMIT somecount
```

You can probably accelerate this query with a compound index on `(orgID, eventTimestamp)`. (If the table uses MyISAM, include the PK in the index like so `(orgID, eventTimestamp, eventID)`.

Then do this to get the data details from the rows you want.

```
SELECT event.eventID, event.orgID, event.objectType, event.action, event.objectID, 
       event.logEventID, event.eventTimestamp, event.userID, event.source, 
       event.additionalDetails, event.insertByUserID, event.insertDateTime, 
       event.modifyByUserID, event.modifyDateTime 
  FROM event
  JOIN (
         SELECT eventID
           FROM event
          WHERE orgID = 100
            AND eventTimestamp >= somevalue
          ORDER BY eventID
          LIMIT somecount
       ) sel ON event.eventID  = sel.eventID
 ORDER BY event.eventID
```

This works because it sorts, then discards, just the primary key values. That's cheaper.

There's another optimization possible if your eventTimestamp and eventID values are both in strictly ascending order. That is, if every row you insert has the current timestamp, you can take advantage of that fact.

```
SELECT event.eventID, event.orgID, event.objectType, event.action, event.objectID, 
       event.logEventID, event.eventTimestamp, event.userID, event.source, 
       event.additionalDetails, event.insertByUserID, event.insertDateTime, 
       event.modifyByUserID, event.modifyDateTime 
  FROM event
  JOIN (
         SELECT eventID
           FROM event
          WHERE orgID = 100
            AND eventID >= (SELECT MIN(eventID) 
                              FROM event 
                             WHERE eventTimestamp >= somevalue)
          ORDER BY eventID
          LIMIT somecount
       ) sel ON event.eventID  = sel.eventID
 ORDER BY event.eventID
```

Use an index on `orgID` and another on `eventTimestamp` for this kind of of query. It works because every row with a timestamp >= than your starting timestamp has an eventID >= the one in the first row matching the time criterion.

Hopefully your eventTimestamp column has the `BIGINT` or `DOUBLE` data  type. Javascript timestamps (milliseconds since the UNIX epoch) don't fit in 32-bit integers. If you index things correctly, the larger datatype won't make much diffference to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have both of these:

```
INDEX(orgid, eventTimestamp)
INDEX(orgid, eventID)
```

The Optimizer can use either of them, and *may* pick the better one based on statistics.  Adding extra columns to either one will not speed up *this* query.  The second index will avoid filesort, but *may not* be faster.

If the output is going to a web page, I suggest that `LIMIT 10001` is unwieldy.